# Rejected hermeneutics doubtfully true

Tags: sources-mekorot, hermeneutics, talmudic-methodology

The *gemarra* often employs the different types of *derashos*/hermeneutics such as *kal vachomer*/*a fortiori* arguments and *hekesh*/juxtaposition of phrases or terms. Also  often, is these *derashos* are rejected due to some flaw, known as a *pircha*. For example, a law can't be derived from one verse to another through a *hekesh* because there's some special reason the first verse should have the law, which doesn't apply to the second verse.

Rabbi Yosef Tzvi Salant in [**Be'er Yosef**](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47092&st=&pgnum=335)  suggests that when a *pircha* is introduced, the ***derasha*** isn't **totally rejected**. It **remains a doubt**, and in fact it could still prove true, if some later evidence appears that it's true.

I was wondering if this is his own insight, or is there an earlier source for such an idea, or is this not even a novelty, but the basic understanding of *derashos*/*pirchos*.

Comment: How is this practically different from saying that when a derasha is refuted we don’t know the law?

Comment: @Alex I don't know about practical difference, but it will affect if you can answer his question with the answer he gives in the link :-)

Comment: @Alex I put emphasis on the fact that it's **doubtfully** true, as opposed to definitely not true

Comment: Slightly similar Yerushalmi sheviis 1.1

Comment: It sounds just like a logical point. If you reject a drasha, it doesn't tell you anything about the din. It doesn't logically prove that the din derived by the drasha is not true.

Comment: @Daniel I think his point is the **derasha** is doubtfully true, not the **din**

Comment: The Ramchal wrote a couple of sefarim on logic esp. as applied to Gemara (derech tevunos and sefer hahigayon). From what I remember, once a kal vachomer has a pircha  asked on it, it is no longer a valid proof at all, and even if the halacha were true, it would need a different source. The exception is if the pircha itself is disproved, leaving the original kal vachomer.

Comment: the פרי מגדים (in his פתיחה כוללת) says that the reason that אין עונשין מן הדין is because really every ק"ו is only a safeik, because maybe there's a פירכא, I would guess that he argues on the be'er yosef

Comment: @yih613 that's the maharsha in sanhedrin, I believe. Where do you see that idea contradicting the beer Yosef? The two ideas can both be true?

Comment: @robev your right that they can both be true, but it would seem curious if it's considered a sofek before it was מופרך and is still a sofek after it's מופרך...

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I always wondered about this. Tannaim are constantly suggesting kal v'chomers and other limudim, and then another tanna shows up with a pircha. Perhaps that means that the first one just overlooked it. But it seems like you can pretty much always find some kind of pircha. I always wondered if the first tanna didn't overlook it, but didn't want to use it. And then somehow once the second tanna brought it anyhow, you have to move on and try something else? Needs work, but it always bothered me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a novelty, as it logically follows. It doesn't even require advanced Torah knowledge to show this, just a bit of critical thinking!

Consider the following conversation:

> Person A: Yosef has a job.
>
> Person B: How do you know?
>
> Person A: I saw him at a cash register at a grocery store, so he must work there.
>
> Person B: Actually, he was just buying food. He doesn't work there!
>
> Person A: Oh! So I was wrong. So, does that mean Yosef doesn't have a job?
>
> Person B: No. Yosef could be unemployed, but he could also work work somewhere else. Just because your proof that he has a job is wrong, doesn't mean the conclusion is definitely wrong too.

Likewise, for any halakha, just because some particular derivation of it is incorrect, doesn't mean the conclusion must be. That isn't to say the conclusion definitely *is* correct, either, of course. We're essentially back to where we started - it might be true or it might not be and that's all we know. This is what Rabbi Salant is saying. (As a side note, recall that lots of the time rabbis agree on the law in The Talmud, but not on how it was derived. This shows that just because one particular proof was invalid for law X, it's not necessarily the case that no proof is valid for law X.)

This principle comes up in more places than just Jewish law - you can expect to see it in formal logic, mathematical proofs, and some types of non-Jewish philosophy.

Comment: Seems to me that Rabbi Salant is saying more than that. He is saying that a pircha isn't absolute.

Answer (score 0):

The Ramchal wrote a couple of sefarim on logic esp. as applied to Gemara (derech tevunos and sefer hahigayon). From what I remember, once a kal vachomer has a pircha  asked on it, it is no longer a valid proof at all, and even if the halacha were true, it would need a different source. The exception is if the pircha itself is disproved, leaving the original kal vachomer.

The reason is that kal vachomer's and other middos have rules, and if the rules aren't satisfied, it is not a derasha.

Comment: Can you find where he says this? Although this doesn't necessarily answer the question, but is more of an opposing opinion to this Be'er Yosef. Either way, I'm curious.

Comment: Derech Tevunos perek 8. It isn't so black and white there, but what I understood from context is that once your kal vachomer has a pircha, it no longer teaches anything, the reason being if there is one exception to the relative kal vs. chomur of the subjects, there might be another, so you are back to square one.